# Unable to authenticate to SSL site in java: "pathLenConstraint violated - this cert must be the last cert in the certification path"

Tags: java, http, ssl

I'm trying to read from a secure (i.e. SSL) web page, in Java code.
I'm trying to use both URLConnection (java.net) and Apache's HTTPClient.
In both cases, when I make the request, I get this exception:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path validation failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   basic constraints check failed:
>   pathLenConstraint violated - this cert
>   must be the last cert in the
>   certification path    at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:150)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1518)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:174)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:106)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:495)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:433)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:818)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1030)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1057)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1041)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:402)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:934)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
>     at
>   com.sap.river.coghead.rest.Main.testJavaHTTPConnection(Main.java:45)
>     at
>   com.sap.river.coghead.rest.Main.main(Main.java:32)
>   Caused by:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path validation failed:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   basic constraints check failed:
>   pathLenConstraint violated - this cert
>   must be the last cert in the
>   certification path    at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:187)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:139)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:172)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:320)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:841)
>     ... 13 more Caused by:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:
>   basic constraints check failed:
>   pathLenConstraint violated - this cert
>   must be the last cert in the
>   certification path    at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:139)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:316)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178)
>     at
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:206)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:182)
>     ... 18 more

Note that I've succeeded in establishing a non-ssl connection, to a different host though.
I'm also able to view this page using the browser - the certificates are validated correctly there.

Do you I need to somehow change the order of certificates as they are retrieved from the server?
Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,

Lior

Answer (score 6):

I dug in further and the answer lies in the fact that I needed to import the necessary certificates into the keystore used by the JVM to authenticate SSL.
The key store is the 'cacerts' file under the jre/lib/security folder in the jre that is used to run the program.

I manually exported the site's certificates - all of them.
Then I imported it into my default keystore using the 'keytool' utility provided by Sun. Note that you have to import them in the correct order.

I then put the new keystore instead of the JRE's one - and it worked.

I guess it would've been better to import the certificates directly to the JRE's keystore, but the tool asked me for a password which i didn't know.

I believe there's also a way to program around this more easily, just haven't found it yet. I'll be happy to get some pointers (TrustManager class in JSSE?).

Finally, some credit. This post here: http://javaishdiscoveries.blogspot.com/2009/02/battle-with-cacerts-and-https.html helped to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but Java allows you to change the default SLLSocketFactory.

Comment: yes, I imagine I need to do something in that area. Just need to investigate it further.

Thanks anyway,
 - Lior

Comment: FYI, the password for the default Java certificates keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts is 'changeit'

Answer (score 0):

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: basic constraints check failed: pathLenConstraint violated - this cert must be the last cert in the certification path at

**pathLenConstraint**

see (Note about certificate chains) in

http://groups.google.com/group/google-checkout-developers-forum/web/google-checkout-and-ssl-certificates?version=49

google says it may be problem with certificate chain order, I have just found that my cert is not in order, not fixed yet, working on it. I will update this later.

---

old post:

Have almost the same problem.

Adding certificate manualy to keystore helps, but I'd prefer to do it more automatically, with my client.

So my solution:

I will use keystore just for this one app, and one host
1. keystore does not exist - create with some generated password
2. save password in config file
3. ask user (or dont) whether he wants to accept this certificate
4. if so - save it to keystore, and use it when needed

Is this a good solution? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with certificate chain order.
It was: A->C->B, but should be A->B->C, once we fixed chain order the application started to work.

---

I havent personally fixed the certs. but this post was helpful

http://groups.google.com/group/google-checkout-api-troubleshooting/browse_thread/thread/99862c11d37d3127

Comment: How did you found out the chain order of certificates?